# Private access errors

Tags: java, class

I'm having trouble with a problem I'm working on for class.
The errors occurring are

`TC1.java:17: error: myQuantity has private access in CheckItem`

```
items[i].myQuantity=quantities[i];
```

and

`TC1.java:20: error: myPrice has private access in CheckItem`

```
a[i]=items[i].myPrice*((items[i].mySalesTax\100)+1);
```

This is the code I currently have.

```
public class CheckItem 
{ 
  private double myPrice, 
                 mySalesTax; 

  private int    myQuantity = 1; 

  public CheckItem( double price, double salesTax ) 
  { 
    myPrice = price; 
    mySalesTax = salesTax; 
  } 

  public int getQuantity() 
  { 
    return myQuantity;  
  } 

  public void setQuantity( int qty ) 
  { 
    myQuantity = qty;  
  } 

  public double lineItemTotal() 
  { 
   return roundMoney((myPrice*myQuantity)*((mySalesTax/100)+1)); 


  } 

  public static double roundMoney( double amount ) 
  { 
    return (int)(100 * amount + 0.5) / 100.0; 
  } 
  public static void setQuantities( CheckItem[] items, int[] quantities )
  {
   for (int i=0;i<quantities.length;i++){
       items[i].myQuantity=quantities[i];
   }


  }
  public static double[] lineItemTotals( CheckItem[] items )
  {
      double[] a=new double[items.length];
   for (int i=0;i<items.length;i++){
       a[i]=items[i].myPrice*((items[i].mySalesTax/100)+1);
   }
   return a;

  }


}
```

Comment: Can you paste your code in a file as it is and run `javac CheckItem.java`. And then paste compilation errors as it is. This is obviously edited version that has no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that static methods can't access private instance variables. Define getters and setters for those variables, and use them:

```
items[i].setQuantity(quantities[i]);

a[i]=items[i].getPrice()*((items[i].getSalesTax()\100)+1);
```

and it will work.

Comment: Well, actually it only worked for the quantity problem

Comment: Like I said, you need to add the `getPrice()` and `getSalesTax()` methods to `CheckItem`. They would return `myPrice` and `mySalesTax` respectively.

Comment: Is there any other way? I'm working in eiMACs and it only asks me to define the lineItemTotals method with the rest of the code already given.

Comment: what you actually should do is use the line `a[i]=items[i].lineItemTotal()` instead, why else did you define that method?

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles fine. If you are trying to access private members outside this class you would get private access error during compilation. In that case standard fix is to provide setters and/or getters.

** EDIT **
Seems like there is confusion about allowed access. You can NOT access any instance variables from static methods/context DIRECTLY! But you CAN access instance variables via instance itself as shown here:

```
class Test {

  private int s = 123;

  void instPrint() {
    System.out.println(s); // fine
  }

  static void statPrint(Test ss) {
    System.out.println(ss.s); // this is fine too!
    // System.out.println(s); // does not compile obviously
  }
}
```

This is the same case as in the code above. This has nothing to do with access modifiers because it's all happening in the same class.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question because it's not very clear what the problem is. I compiled your class without any errors.

Comment: You can refer to private members inside of the class - that's not a problem

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov A static method cannot access instance variables directly

Comment: @JNYRanger directly - no because it would not know which instance this instance variable belongs to, but via an object - yes: `items[i].myQuantity` is ok there.

Comment: @JNYRanger I made an example for you in my answer

Answer (score -1):

Your code declares these two member variables in class `CheckItem` with the `private` scope. This means no other classes can access them directly on a `CheckItem` instance:

```
private double myPrice, 
             mySalesTax;
```

If you want class `TC1` to be able to read or modify them, declare them in CheckItem.java as `public`.  Alternatively, and generally a better practice, you could add public methods to CheckItem.java to allow other classes to access their values:

```
public double getMyPrice() {
  return this.myPrice;
}
public void setMyPrice(double price) {
  this.myPrice = price;
}
public double getMySalesTax() {
  return this.mySalesTax;
}
public void setMySalesTax(double st) {
  this.mySalesTax = st;
}
public int getMyQuantity() {
  return this.myQuantity;
}
public void setMyQuantity(int newQty) {
  this.myQuantity = newQty;
}
```

Then, in TC1.java you'd use these methods instead of direct access:

```
items[i].setMyQuantity(quantities[i]);
```

and

```
a[i]=items[i].getMyPrice()*((items[i].getMySalesTax()\100)+1);
```